# Why Location Determination Does Not Work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to show the user's location with the following code:

HTML:

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<input type="button" value="try it" onclick="getLocation()" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
               function showPosition(position) 
                 {alert("Latitude: ");},
                    function error1(){},
                      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000});
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
}
```

All I got is nothing when I run the code above and click the button. Any one knows why?

Comment: Please add to your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewL. no error

Comment: @Frxstrem I want to figure out why my if and else statement is not implemented.

Comment: your code works as posted - check the console log, because if you're using Chrum, it probably has a message about non-secure network

Comment: Your error handling callback doesn't do anything. Put a `console.log()` (or `alert()`) inside `error1()` and I think you'll find that `.getCurrentPosition()` is calling it.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Why people still down voting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your error callback function you need to have more detailed error reporting:

```
var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) 
      {
          alert('Only secure origins are allowed');
      }
      else
      {
          alert("Please enable location services on.");
      }
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
      break;
  }
};

function getLocation() 
{
        if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function showPosition(position) {alert("Latitude: ");},
                browserGeolocationFail,
                {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000});
        }   
        else 
        {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the message that I got is "please enable locations services" Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The script element at the end will have been parsed by the time the
>   user clicks the button. (Though it shouldn't be *after* the closing
>   `</html>` tag.) -@nnnnnn

Note also, this warning is logged at `console`

```
getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. 
To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/VR1lFgL7mY0bsxZVt6tc?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<input type="button" value="try it" onclick="getLocation()" />

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo"); 

function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("in getLocation"); navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showPosition(position) {alert("Latitude: ");},function error1(){},{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000});
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script element at the end will have been parsed by the time the user clicks the button. (Though it shouldn't be *after* the closing `</html>` tag.)

Comment: I'am still having the problem if and else are not implemented. The functions inside the getCurrentPosition is not working.

Comment: @AymenKareem See updated post.